# How to merge transaction data by updating columns in master rows

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I need to update a master df (df1) with data from multiple records in a transaction df (df2) where the 'id_number' values match in both frames. The master includes a combination of static and dynamic columns. I want to detect changes in values column by column and if changed, update the master column with the latest value and update an associated master column with valence data.

I tried to pack the transaction rows into a single record, but can't see how to do this without old-school coding of multiple embedded ifs and loops.

```
    ...
    # Data patterns:
    # open master
    df_master = pd.DataFrame({'id':['100'], 'date': ['2018'], 'value':['350000'], 'value_valence':['1'], 'lat':['36.608257'], 'lon':['121.812232'], 'age':['34']})
    # open transactions
    df_transaction = pd.DataFrame({'id':['100'], 'date': ['2019'], 'value':['380000'], 'lat':['36.608257'], 'lon':['-121.812232'], 'age':['35']})

    # After update: Master = 100,2019,380000,2,36.608257,-121.812232,35

    # sort transactions in id, date order (master is in id order with unique ids and all ids in transaction are in master)
    df_transactions = df_transactions.sort_values(by = ['id','date'])
    # pseudo:
    for i in df_transactions:
        if df_master['id'] == df_transaction['id']:
            for j in df_transactions.row:
                if column(j).value != df_master.column(j):
                    # update the master column with the new value
                    df_master.column(j) = df_transactions.column(j)
                    # update the associated valence column
                    if df_master.column(j) > df_transactions.column(j): 
                        df_master.column(j+1) = df_master.column(j+1) + 1
                    else df_master.column(j+1) = df_master.column(j+1) - 1
```

I know the above conflates syntaxes and is crude, and that some combination of iloc, loc, lambda and other bits I don't fully grok could do this more efficiently.

Any help is appreciated, even if it's 'go do tut x' or such.

Answer (score 0):

Was hoping SO would accelerate my progress, but devised a viable answer to my question before anyone chimed in:

Doing an inner join of transactions to the master enables vectorizing transforms. This produces rows with columns from both files, repeating the master data for every transaction row. The column names have _x appended for the master and _y appended for the transactions.

```
...
dfmerge = pd.merge(df_master, df_transactions, on='id', how='inner')

dfmerge.loc[(dfmerge.value_x != dfmerge.value_y), 'value'] = dfmerge.value_y 
dfmerge.loc[(dfmerge.value_x == dfmerge.value_y), 'value'] = dfmerge.value_x 
...
```

I just repeat the second line above for each of the columns changing the logic to suit the transform required.